# How to change the TAB character color in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I like having the tab character, but I do not know where to change the color.
The closest I have found is changing the whitespace character. [image]

I've tried this screen. But AS will not apply the color or save any color I choose.
Is there somewhere else?

[image]